# Localization in Salesforce

Tags: visualforce, locale

Here we are discussing about localization in Visualforce, and we know these two solutions:
1) use cookies
2) use a parameter on the URL that specifies the language selected by the user

Is there any other viable approach to this problem?

Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 5):

Best practise would involve:

- creating [Custom Labels](https://login.salesforce.com/101) to reference translatable text,
- using [Translation Workbench](https://login.salesforce.com/ui/setup/Setup?setupid=LabelWorkbench) to create and avail the translations,
- letting users set their Language/Locale on their profile,

Comment: Thank You sir, I might have written my question in a wrong way though. We are not looking for best practice on how to do localization, but how to let a user choose proper locale.

Comment: Best bet would be to ask a new question @MicheleFestini

Comment: Here is the link in case anyone wants to find the follow up question: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/11778/911