# change Locale in Visualforce

Tags: visualforce, locale

Here we are discussing about localization in Visualforce, we know best practices that involve HOW to implement localization, Custom Labels and such.
We are looking for a smart way to implement the capability for a Web-authenticated-user ( but this must also apply to Guest as well) to change locale upon his/her desire.
We know these two solutions: 
1) use cookies, good solution but bad if final user blocks cookies 
2) use a parameter on the URL that specifies the language selected by the user, not so good as this would require to refactor a lot of visualforce code (mainly all the navigation links) as the parameter should be present in every request.

Is there any other viable approach to this problem?

Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had a similar issue and decided to go with cookies and to display a notification to the user, that he needs to enable cookies in order to use the page.